# Text Font is still Bold after setting font-weight to 100

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want my font weight like heading of this [website](http://www.alliedinfoline.com/demo/ardentengineers.in/) h2 element  
I am using the below css i tried every thing but font-weight of h2 element on my website is still bold then this

**CSS:**

```
h2 {
 color: #2598ea;
 font: normal normal 300 38px / 51px "Open Sans", Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans- serif;
 text-transform: none;
}
```

Really i don't know what is the problem with this code

Comment: That code works, so there might be something overriding it.

Comment: but there is no css for overriding this is the problem but still i am testing what is problem with this

Comment: Try to added `!important` at end of **font** property

Comment: i did like font-weight:100 !important; But no luck

Comment: Open Sans is a custom font and you need to embed it before you can use it in your css

Comment: If you have linked to the Open Sans font, have you included the 300 font weight in that call?

Comment: How do you include the font? Are you sure you have the 300 font weight installed?

Comment: you need to add <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> to the head section

Comment: Can any one tell me how to embed Open sans to my css it will be very helpfull for me

Comment: @ Liviu A a lot i got it to work with it. And today i learned a new thing thanks a lot :):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back to basic here I think is more of the issue. Do you have the right font-weight loaded up from google fonts? When you select a font you like from them make sure you pick out the appropriate font weight.

If it isn't make sure you put it in your html head with the following code.

Check my code pen for how to do this.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Travo100/pen/rdLmG

```
<!-- font-weight of 300 included here -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h2> Welcome to Ardent Engineers </h2>

h2{
  color: #2598ea;
  /*font weight of 300 here*/
  font: normal normal 300 38px / 44px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add properties of normal class with !important. So it always apply.

```
CSS: 
h2
{
    color: #2598ea;
    font: normal normal 300 38px / 51px "Open Sans", Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana,    sans-serif;text-transform: none; 
    font-weight : normal !important ;
}
```

But I think you can add new class for normal font and explicitly given to the object.

```
<h2 class="normalfnt" ...>
    .normalfnt
    {
            font-weight : normal !important ;  
    }
```

Comment: what you think i applied everything what i can thing and do. I did it already but no luck at all :(

Comment: I edit with h2 element. you can define and then apply the font normal class as important. So it will definitely effect and this class as given explicitly, no other h2 element effect. Or give your url or html page

Comment: i used  <link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> suggested by @ Liviu A this includes the font in my css

Answer (score 0):

That is not system font. The font itself, it is coming up with the style. Basically our system  font will come up very boldly, if you give 38px. In your case it is taking the system font and it is applying as it is. If you give Bold it will add more bold to the normal text.

Suppose if you installed the same font "Open Sans" in your system, you will get the same result.

Comment: so what could be the solution of this problem

Comment: I told you need to install the same font in your system or create web font using some online tool.

Comment: As per my knowledge this font are by default  supported and if i am able to see the similar font for another website on my system then why a am not able to see similar with my website

Comment: As far I knows if the define font is not on your system its look for another similar font which is available in System .

Comment: Simple. They included this font in their solution.

Comment: If you want to use custom font you have to upload the desire font on your server and have to call it using `@font-face` CSS method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing system fonts with web fonts. In this case, the website you linked has loaded **both** a normal/roman cut of the typeface as well as a bold cut. Inside a `@font-face` declaration you can set different weights to different files.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-bold-webfont.eot');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-roman-webfont.eot');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Both of these link to different files, but when a CSS rule specifies `bold`, the first declaration is used. When `normal` is specified, the second is used.

In your example, you need to use the light cut of the font to achieve a lighter font.